# Careers and favorites tags swap positions on main page and questions page

Tags: discussion, user-interface, design

This is a relatively minor UI annoyance.  On the main page (https://stackoverflow.com/), the block of Favorite Tags are immediately below the Ask Question button and above the careers ad:

[image: tags over careers]

but on the questions page the careers ad is above the favorite tags:

[image: careers over ads]

The different positions is only a minor UI annoyance, but there's often some delay in loading the careers ad, which means that the favorite tags jump down when the careers ad appears. If the browser is sluggish, it's not uncommon that I click on a favorite tag only to end up on the careers page (because the careers ad is loaded by the time the click is processed), and this is a bigger annoyance.

Is there a reason for the difference, and if there's not some compelling reason to have the careers ad above the favorites tags, could the favorites tags always be placed above?

#### Update

As of Sep. 17, 2013, it appears that things have shifted around a bit, with the main page looking like this (notably, with no careers ad):

[image: main page on 2013/9/17]

and the questions page looking like this (with the careers ad):

[image: questions page as of 2013/9/17]

Comment: I'm not quite sure about which tags this should have, and specifically whether this should be [bug] or not.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for the edits!

Comment: This has happened to me quite a bit on my tablet, where the computing power is not as high as my desktop machine: *"If the browser is sluggish, it's not uncommon that I click on a favorite tag only to end up on the careers page (because the careers ad is loaded by the time the click is processed), ..."*

Comment: @chuex I'm both happy and sad that I'm not the only one.  I don't mind the ad not being visible immediately, but I wish that at the very least, the size was known in advance so that the page layout would not change unexpectedly.